# regexp patterns to match different type of datas

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a database (mysql) text field, with different data:

- data1 - individual numbers, separated with commas: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15...n  (where n can be any positive integer)
- data2 - text, separated with comma: Lorem ipsum, dolor, sit amet, consectetur, adipiscing,elit, Ut et, sollicitudin, enim, vel, consectetur lacus

No start and end comma allowed in data, spaces may come before and/or start of comma or after comma for e.g. 2,3, 4,5 , 6,7 or Lorem ipsum, dolor, sit amet, etc. which spaces may now count in the match.

I need to search in a few different ways in this data, so I need regexp patterns to use with search:

- pattern A: to match a number in data1. if I search for 1, as a result, I just need 1, not 11, 12, etc.,

right now I have: `[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*`

- pattern B: to match a range of numbers: if the field contains (at least one of) the numbers between two given numbers.
- pattern C: to match one of the full strings separated by the comas in the data2. like: if I search for ***sit***, I got no result, but if I seach for ***sit amet***, I got result.

Can anyone help me with these? Is the one I have for Pattern A the best way to do it, and how can I match the range(Pattern B) and the comma delimited strings (Pattern C)?

Comment: Your pattern A requirement is doable, but the other 2 basically are not, not without a massive SQL olympics effort.  What you _should_ do here is to _normalize_ your data.  Get each ID and text entry onto a separate line, with numbers and text in separate columns.  This is good design, and will make your life much easier.

Comment: Unfortunatelly its not doable, the data is given, but thanks

Comment: Please provide table structure with some example data provide example data on sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex. 
I will show you a trick by using a MySQL number generator in combination with nested SUBSTRING_INDEX functions. 
if you need to support more CSV add a new

```
   CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) AS record_[number]
```

**Query**

This query will generate numbers from 1 to 100.
So the final query can support up to 100 separated values.

```
SELECT 
 (@number  := @number + 1) AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) AS record_1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) AS record_2
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number := 0 ) AS init_user_param
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c314ca/5

Now we are going to extract the values from the comma separated string with

**Query**

Replace [position] with a number from 0 - ... which value you want to extract from the comma separated strings.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15', ',', [position]), ',', -1) AS split;
```

or

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Lorem ipsum, dolor, sit amet, consectetur, adipiscing,elit, Ut et, sollicitudin, enim, vel, consectetur lacus ', ',', [position]), ',', -1) AS split;
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c314ca/16

Now we know the basics we are going to combine both queries to a working solution. 
 
This query will convert all comma separated values into records. 
Because i don't know the table structure iám assuming it's something like

```
CREATE TABLE [name] (
    data1 TEXT
  , data2 TEXT
);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data1, ',', generator.number), ',', -1) AS split
FROM (

  SELECT 
   (@number  := @number + 1) AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) AS record_1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) AS record_2
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number := 0 ) AS init_user_param
) 
 AS generator
CROSS JOIN
 Table1

UNION ALL 

SELECT
  DISTINCT 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data2, ',', generator.number), ',', -1) AS split
FROM (

  SELECT 
   (@number2  := @number2 + 1) AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) AS record_1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) AS record_2
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @number2 := 0 ) AS init_user_param
) 
 AS generator
CROSS JOIN
 Table1
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a19fc5/6

We break it down i little parts.

> pattern A: to match a number in data1. if I search for 1, as a result,
>   I just need 1, not 11, 12, etc.,

Because we now have records instead of comma separated values we can simply use the last query as delivered table add a WHERE clause.

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a19fc5/10

> pattern B: to match a range of numbers: if the field contains (at
>   least one of) the numbers between two given numbers.

Now the WHERE clause is a simple BETWEEN clause

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a19fc5/11

> pattern C: to match one of the full strings separated by the comas in
>   the data2. like: if I search for sit, I got no result, but if I seach
>   for sit amet, I got result.

Now you can use LIKE

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a19fc5/14

Answer (score 0):

Pattern A:  To search for a number in a commalist:

```
WHERE FIELD(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13')
```

Or

```
WHERE '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13' REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
```

This checks for "1" surrounded by "word boundaries".

Pattern B:  Not easy.

Pattern C:

```
WHERE CONCAT(',', 'dolor, sit amet, etc', ',') REGEXP ', *sit amet *,';
```

This tacks on commas, then checks for the word being optionally surrounded by space(s), then necessarily commas.